# Method of Router class is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, static-methods

I am writing a middleware to check for authentication of a user, and want to shorten the amount of repetetive code by writing one function for the entire Router class.
Here's how I do it:

```
const express = require('express')
express.Router.checkAuthorization = (address) => {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        if(req.session.user)
            next()
        else
            Router.redirect(res, address, 401)
    }
}
```

What's more interesting, is that I route Router.redirect using the same principle, and it works just fine:

```
express.Router.redirect = (res, path, status) => {
    res.status(status || 308)
    res.redirect(path)
}
```

Albeit, when using it in an instance of a router, it says that checkAuthorization is not a function, even though when I console.log it, it says that it is an anonymous function.
Here's how I do it:

```
const { Router } = require('express')
router.get('/profile', Router.checkAuthorization('/authorize'), 
controller.displayUserProfile)
```

Why doesn't it recognize it as a function?

Comment: Are you sure both cases attach to the same `Router` instance? Why not to keep the middlewares as regular functions and avoid the binding?

Comment: I would like to create a static method for the entire class Router, so it's not bound to any particular instance.

Comment: Ok, it feels like a little brittle pattern for me as it relies on the fact that express Router gets patched properly somewhere in the code. That said, I think you can still do it with static methods by defining a module (file) for patching and exposing `Router` from there to import for example.